# is it possible to use html code in android?

Tags: android

i would like to add a widget that i found from a website into my android app.is that possible?this is the code,as i get it from the site:

```
<iframe src="http://www.mykosmos.gr/loc_mk/wforecast_widget.asp?city_code=0032&bcolor=F0F0F0&fcolor=000000&font=Trebuchet MS&pos=hor" frameborder="0" height="180" width="430"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show the html response as part of your View, not having the user able to interact with it and not needing any javascript to run, then I think the Android WebView would give you what you need.

It allows you to embed the rendered page into a standard Android layout, but does not allow any interaction with the content.

Check out the API docs for [android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html.) Note that the first answer confuses WebView with launching the Web browser via an intent. WebViews allow embedding.